# Trying to use Apache Directory Studio to edit LDIF file results in "Permission Denied"

Tags: linux, centos, openldap

I have created a Linux CentOS 7 VM, and on it, I've installed OpenLDAP.  Now, I need to modify the file `olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif`. This is proving to be a challenge. I'd MUCH rather use a GUI tool than the command prompt. And a little bit of Google led me to Apache Directory Studio.

I *think* I have it installed correctly?  It doesn't show up anywhere under the "Applications" dropdown. (should it?)  I just extracted it into a new folder I named "Applicaitons", and I am able to execute it ok.

The file I need to open and edit is located here:

```
etc/openldap/slap.d/c=config
```

When I navigate there directly, I have to stop and enter my password when I get to `slap.d`

[image]

The problem I have is that when I try to open the file in question from within Apache Directory Studio using `File > Open File`, when I then try and drill into `slap.d` I get this error:

[image]

I've tried a few things that (might) work on windows, like looking for Right-Click > Run As Admin, etc.  I tried to execute Apache Directory Studio from a command prompt using `sudo`... that got me nowhere.

Not sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 2):

With Apache Directory studio, you also don't change the files manually (which is what would happen if what you tried worked). Instead, it's a graphical tool that will help you to perform the LDAP operations to alter the config.

For this to work, you need to add an LDAP connection (bottom left, under "Connections"), point it to the LDAP server (whicht might be localhost in your case), and configure the Base DN as `cn=config`.

Offhand, I don't know the default values that a fresh OpenLDAP installation on CentOS creates for this. Maybe someone else can chime in here.

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/587721/basic-openldap-setup-using-slapd-d-configuration/587742#587742. This likely should work on CentOS 7 as well.

Comment: ok, thank you for this. The more I know, the more I know I don't know.  I need to spend more time looking at the docs for Apache Directory Studio.  I am flying so blind it's pathetic. I don't know the first thing about Linux or OpenLDAP.  As you say, I am going to need to figure out the default connection values for a fresh install.