# `ldapmodify` not working - doesn't change the file content

Tags: linux, centos, openldap

I'm following the steps in this thread:
[Basic openldap setup using slapd.d configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/587721/basic-openldap-setup-using-slapd-d-configuration/587742#587742)

I created and saved my own .ldif file with the changes I needed and saved it as `changes.ldif`. Here is the contents of the file I made:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify

add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}oRvzr9r1qQ7Cn3xN/efmeKJQzwS0wK6z

replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=softura,dc=com

replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=softura,dc=com
```

Then I executed the `ldapmodify` command:

```
ldapmodify -a -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f changes.ldif
```

And I was told:

> modifying entry "olcDatabse={2}hdb,cn=config"

So far so good, right? But if I then open the file `olcDatabse={2}hdb.ldib`... nothing has changed.

**EDIT:**

I've changed the content of my ldif file to:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}oRvzr9r1qQ7Cn3xN/efmeKJQzwS0wK6z
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=softura,dc=com
-
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=softura,dc=com
```

Now when I execute the command, I get this:

> ldap_modify: Inappropriate matching (18)
>
> additional info: modify/add: olcRootPW: no equality matching rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of my problem was that a row for `olcRootPW` already existed. This seemed to be causing an abort at that point, as none of the following two `replace` commands were happening.

So, the immediate problem has been resolved.

However.... Now, olcRootDN and olcSuffix are being properly replaced. But, the existing row:

```
olcRootPW: e1NTSEF9b1J2enI5cjFxUTdDbjN4Ti9lZm1lS0pRendTMHdLNno=..
```

is being replaced NOT with:

```
olcRootPW: {SSHA}oRvzr9r1qQ7Cn3xN/efmeKJQzwS0wK6z
```

It just remains the same. I will open a new post for this.

Answer (score 2):

Check the syntax of your `changes.ldif`. In my example, there are lines with just a `-` in there. These denote the end of the data block for an LDAP operation (like `add` or `replace`).

See `man 5 ldif` and [RFC 2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849).

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}oRvzr9r1qQ7Cn3xN/efmeKJQzwS0wK6z
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=softura,dc=com
-
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=softura,dc=com
```

LDIF files are quite arcane...

Comment: Thanks Sven!  See the edit to my op.

Comment: Also, YES! This is very arcane. I tried yesterday to set up Apache Directory Studio, but I have NO IDEA what values to enter for all of the options, and I can't get it connected. I'm going to have to fight that battle next, but I want to get this solved first.

Comment: The error message I am now getting seems to imply that the change has already been made.  Is there a reason I don't see the changes when I open the file `olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif`?